# Creating a S3 bucket in Amazon AWS with boto in python fails ...

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto

```
import boto
import boto.s3
import boto.s3.connection

conn = boto.s3.connect_to_region(
'us-west-2', 
aws_access_key_id='MY_KEY', 
aws_secret_access_key='MY_ACCESS_KEY'
)

conn.create_bucket('bucket_in_west')
```

And I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/west-tests/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/s3/connection.py", line 621, in create_bucket
    response.status, response.reason, body)
S3ResponseError: S3ResponseError: 400 Bad Request
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>IllegalLocationConstraintException</Code><Message>The unspecified location constraint is incompatible for the region specific endpoint this request was sent to.</Message><RequestId>0C0F09FBC87
```

Does anybody have an answer for how to create an S3 bucket in a specific region with boto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are talking to the `us-west-2` endpoint and you want to create a bucket in that region, you have to specify that when you call `create_bucket`:

```
conn.create_bucket('bucket-in-west', location='us-west-2')
```

Comment: would this apply for the Frankfurt region too? ( different authentication handshake version for this region - don't know why )

Comment: Yes, it applies to any region.  If you want the bucket to be located in that region, you should connect to the S3 endpoint in that region and then specify the region in the ``location`` parameter of ``create_bucket``.

Comment: Hi Mitch and thank you for your comments. Very helpful as usual. One thing to note though ... when connected to a region specific S3 service, one can not create a bucket that contains '_'/underscore in its name ...